# Evaluate $\int_0^xg(t)\,dt$ if $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ and $g(x+5)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ and $f$ is an odd function. If $g(x+5)=f(x)$ then evaluate $\int_0^xg(t)\,dt$.

I found that $$g(x)=F(x)-F(0)$$ and $$g'(x)=f(x)$$

Then $$\int^x_0 F(t)-F(0) \,dt$$

I dont know what to do next, but I guess the answer is $\int^{x+5}_5 f(t) \,dt$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x+5)=f(x)$ means that $g(x)$ is nothing more than $f(x)$ shifted $5$ units to the left. Since $f(x)$ is an odd function, its graph is symmetric with respect to the origin. Therefore, $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)\,dt$ should be equal to the same area you get by evaluating $\int_{5}^{x+5}f(t)\,dt$.